Take data from Lead Record when condition or filter criteria matches and ignore the records between current row and selected record (lead row)
How can I write a CTE in SQL Server to get the date from the preceding row for the person that has Type = NA.
If there are multiple preceding rows with NA then take the first one when sorted by dt_eff asc.
If there are any other types between start of record and type = NA then these records should be ignored.  Only consider other Types for the same person when previous type is ended (Person 124 Scenario).
Source Data
Person    Type     dt_eff
123       A        2018-10-23 <Start of record >
123       NA       2018-11-19 <Should be the end date for above and dont select this in output> 
123       NA       2018-12-25 <dont select this in output>
124       A        2020-01-01 <Start of record >
124       B        2020-02-15 <Ignore and dont select in output>
124       NA       2020-05-14 <Should be the end date for start of record and dont select in op>
124       C        2020-10-13 <As the above start record has ended this should be new start>
124       NA       2021-01-15 <should be the end date for second start record>
124       A        2021-05-22 <As the above start record has ended this should be new start>
124       T        2021-08-22 <Ignored and dont select in output>
456       NA       2022-04-19 <Ignore as there is no lag record with valid type>
456       A        2022-05-01 <Start of record and null as end date as there is no type = NA>
456       B        2022-07-15 <Ignore>

Expected Output
Person    Type     dt_start     dt_end
123       A        2018-10-23   2018-11-19
124       A        2020-01-01   2020-05-14
124       C        2020-10-13   2021-01-15
124       A        2021-05-22   NULL
456       A        2022-05-01   NULL

DML and DDL for above source data
CREATE TABLE Person (
  Person INTEGER,
  Type VARCHAR(3),
  dt_eff Date
);

INSERT INTO Person (Person, Type, dt_eff)
VALUES
(123,'A','2018-10-23'),
(123,'NA','2018-11-19'),
(123,'NA','2018-12-25'),
(124,'A','2020-01-01'),
(124,'B','2020-02-15'),
(124,'NA','2020-05-14'),
(124,'C','2020-10-13'),
(124,'NA','2021-01-15'),
(124,'A','2021-05-22'),
(124,'T','2021-08-22'),
(456,'NA','2022-04-19'),
(456,'A','2022-05-01'),
(456,'B','2022-07-15')

Attempt
with cte1 as (
  select *
    , lead(dt_eff) over (partition by Person order by dt_eff) dt_eff_lead
    , lag(Type, 1, Type) over (partition by Person order by dt_eff) type_lag
  from Person
), cte2 as (
  select Person, Type, dt_eff Start_Date
    , dt_eff_lead
    , sum(case when Type <> type_lag and type='NA' then 1 else 0 end)
      over (partition by person order by dt_eff asc
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) TypeGroup
  from cte1
)
select Person, Type, Start_Date as dt_start
  , max(dt_eff_lead) over (partition by Person, TypeGroup) dt_end
from cte2
where Type<>'NA'
order by Person, Start_Date, Type;


Included extra filter (type='NA') in the query you had given in yesterday post.  sum (case when Type <> type_lag and Type='NA' then 1 else 0 end)".   This is giving end date from preceding record where type='NA'. But not sure how effectively we can filter records and make end-date as null when there is no preceding record with type=NA

Added query. need some king of flag column in cte2, where it says ignore this record + dt_end should be null for start record when there is no preceding record with type=NA

I recommend looking into gaps-and-islands

You can do your grouping based by running total number of NA rows:
SELECT  Person, Type
,   dt_start, CASE WHEN cntNA > 0 THEN dt_end END AS dt_end
FROM    (
    SELECT  MIN(dt_eff) OVER(PARTITION BY person, grouping) AS dt_start
    ,   MAX(dt_eff) OVER(PARTITION BY person, grouping) AS dt_end
    ,   COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'NA' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY person, grouping) AS cntNA
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person, grouping ORDER BY dt_eff) AS startrow
    ,   *
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        ,   COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'NA' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY dt_eff ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grouping
        FROM
        (
            VALUES  (123, N'A', N'2018-10-23')
            ,   (123, N'NA', N'2018-11-19')
            ,   (123, N'NA', N'2018-12-25')
            ,   (124, N'A', N'2020-01-01')
            ,   (124, N'B', N'2020-02-15')
            ,   (124, N'NA', N'2020-05-14')
            ,   (124, N'C', N'2020-10-13')
            ,   (124, N'NA', N'2021-01-15')
            ,   (124, N'A', N'2021-05-22')
            ,   (124, N'T', N'2021-08-22')
            ,   (456, N'NA', N'2022-04-19')
            ,   (456, N'A', N'2022-05-01')
            ,   (456, N'B', N'2022-07-15')
        ) t (Person,Type,dt_eff)
    ) x
) x
WHERE   startrow = 1
AND type <> 'NA'


COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'NA' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY dt_eff ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) creates the above grouping value. AND 1 PRECEDING means that first NA is counted towards previous rows, which is what you're looking for grouping-wise.

Then you create min / max date per grouping as well as which is the first row, since you're only interested in one row per group. cntNA contains number of NAs in the group, since you need to NULL out the dt_end for those without any NAs.

Finally, you select what you're looking for. CASE WHEN cntNA > 0 THEN dt_end END creates the open ended dates



Wow. Does this grouping come under "gap and island"? someone recommended me to look into gap and island grouping.  Your query looks like gap and island grouping to me.  Learning new things. This is working as expected and in much efficient way. Will test on big data. Thank You.

Yes, i would say this is a gaps and island technique, one counts the desirable values in some way and create a running group, there are of course a lot of variations on the theme as well. It's very useful in many situations

thank you. very helpful. will start looking into gaps and island going forward along with cte.
